# Row não respeita Padding da Div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, padding

A Row não respeita o padding da div em que esta dentro.
[image: Coloquei a Linha pra Entenderem melhor]

```
div[role="conteudo"]{
            width: 100%;
            padding:0px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #FFF;
        }

<div class="container" role="conteudo">
      {...}
    <div class="row">
       <div class=col-lg-8>
          {...}
       <div class=col-lg-4>
```

Alguem pode me Ajudar?

Comment: O padding está a 0. O problema é a imagem sair? Temos sempre de definir uma `height` ou uma `width` para as imagens

Comment: aconselho tambem a não colocar o height de 100% no conteudo, aplique um height:auto; (para uma div receber uma altura de 100% ele tem que estar dentro de um elemento com uma altura ja definida, e se estiver dentro de uma div com altura já definida a que recebe 100% precisa de um estilo display:block;)

Comment: o problema não é a imagem e sim a col mesmo sem ter as imagens ela da isso, e como se o padding original da content fizesse ela volta, tipo se eu tirar o padding ela fica perfeita no espaco mas ai o meu menu fica com espaco entre as bordas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aplica `float:left;` no seu CSS do row.

Comment: Pronto, retirei o comentario. agora o float é a resposta...

Comment: Não estou entendendo o que vocês estão querendo dizer com isto. A pergunta foi, porque a div ROW não respeita o padding da div CONTENT. Eu respondi, que o problema é a falta do estilo "float:left;" na div row. Não estou fazendo nenhuma pergunta.

Comment: @luisaddor Desculpe o inconveniente das mensagens. Esse tipo de mensagem é automática do sistema. Sua pergunta foi para a fila de análise por ser muito "curta". Seria interessante adicionar mais detalhes, explicando o motivo de sua resposta funcionar.